# Return a column in hql select clause without actually using that column

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a query which returns a list of objects like such:

```
select distinct ref from references where [...]
```

I'd like to order these by a field not on ref but on an association of ref, i.e.:

```
select distinct ref from references where [...] order by ref.foo.name
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Oracle (once the query is translated to SQL) since it can only sort on this column if it's included in the select. Is there any way I can return the column as well, without hibernate actually picking it up? I'd like to just return a List instead of having to muck about with the Object[] arrays it would otherwise return.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible for Oracle to sort a query by a column which is not included in the selection:

```
SQL> select ename from emp
  2  order by empno
  3  /

ENAME
----------
CLARKE
VAN WIJK
PADFIELD
ROBERTSON
BILLINGTON
SPENCER
BOEHMER
RIGBY
SCHNEIDER
CAVE
KULASH
HALL
GASPAROTTO
KISHORE

14 rows selected.
```

SQL>

But as your ORDER BY clause looks a bit peculiar -  `order by ref.foo.name` - perhaps I am missing some subtlety?

**Edit**
Vincent pointed out the subtlety I was missing - the use of `DISTINCT`.

```
SQL> select distinct ename from emp
  2  order by empno
  3  /
order by empno
         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression


SQL>
```

The need to use `DISTINCT` is often indicative of a design flaw, either a missing element in the `WHERE` clause or an insufficiently normalised data model.  Although this does not help the questioner who probably just needs to get a workaround.

Comment: In the OP case this isn't possible because of the DISTINCT. When using DISTINCT it doesn't really make sense to order by something not in the SELECT list.

Comment: I guess I wasn't quite clear. The query is in HQL. There is a many to one association from ref to foo so that there will be one ref.foo.name for every ref. In plain SQL I could just write the join myself and add the field to the select, but I was hoping not to have to rewrite the query.

Answer (score 0):

On the Hibernate side, a simple solution would be that your DAO code takes care of your problem. Your request would add the column.

Your Dao method would receive from Hibernate a List, and translate it.

```
List<Object[]> rawResults = query....;
List<References> results = new ArrayList<References>(rawResults.size());
for(Object[] rawResult : rawResults) {
  results.add(rawResults[0]);
}
return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle when you use an 'aggregation' function (distinct, group by, count, ...) to sort through the results you need to include de desired field in the select clause, because the 'distinct' clause works just like a 'group by', what hibernate is doing is selecting all the columns in your object with 'distinct' aggregation. Maybe you should try to use the 'group by' function in HQL that way hibernate can translate in the correct form your join in the group by function.